# default postgres user and password

Tags: postgresql

I'm just new to postgresql db management. 
I've been playing around with a db that I didn't create. 
Trying to understand the different roles that have been created.

Does the fact that I can log in doing the following mean that the postgres user has no password set up?

```
psql -U postgres
```

I did a

```
`select * from pg_roles`
```

and I can see that there is a password set.
I found this article:  http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4D958A35.8030501@hogranch.com
which seeme to confirm that the postgres user is there by default... 
and you have to explicitly set a password.  It's the second part about the password that I'm not sure about.  Is it blank by default or set to something?

I know that if pg_hba.conf is set to trust everything from 127.0.0.1, then you can log in from the local server without specifying a password.  That might be what's happening in my case... i will test by changing the pg_hba.conf file...
But it'd be nice to know what the default password is for postgres user.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no default password. You can verify this by changing "trust" to "md5" in your `pg_hba.conf` and reloading your config files (eg. `select pg_reload_conf()`. Check for a `~postgres/.pgpass` file as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pg_roles` is not the view that can tell whether a user has a password or not, because the password field is always set to `********` no matter what.

This comes from the definition of this view (taken from version 9.3):

```
select definition from pg_views  where viewname='pg_roles';
```

Result:

```
  SELECT pg_authid.rolname,
     pg_authid.rolsuper,
     pg_authid.rolinherit,
     pg_authid.rolcreaterole,
     pg_authid.rolcreatedb,
     pg_authid.rolcatupdate,
     pg_authid.rolcanlogin,
     pg_authid.rolreplication,
     pg_authid.rolconnlimit,
     '********'::text AS rolpassword
     pg_authid.rolvaliduntil,
     s.setconfig AS rolconfig,
     pg_authid.oid 
    FROM (pg_authid
    LEFT JOIN pg_db_role_setting s
      ON (((pg_authid.oid = s.setrole) AND (s.setdatabase = (0)::oid))));
```

Note how the `rolpassword` column is hardcoded to reveal nothing (We may wonder why it's there at all. Maybe for backward compatibility?)

On the other hand , there is a `pg_shadow` view that displays passwords as they're stored, in a column named `passwd`. This view is only readable by a superuser (typically: the `postgres` user).

Example:

```
create user foo unencrypted password 'foopassword';
create user bar encrypted password 'foopassword';
select usename,passwd from pg_shadow where usename in ('postgres','foo','bar');
```

Result on a vanilla Debian install:

```
 usename  |               passwd                
----------+-------------------------------------
 postgres | 
 foo      | foopassword
 bar      | md50390570d30cb9a2f9cb7476f0763cf51
```

Initially the `postgres` password is often empty, except on Windows for which the installer tends to ask for it. On Unix, `pg_hba.conf` is often set up such that only the OS user `postgres` may log in as the database user `postgres` through Unix socket domains without a password. This is reasonable as a default security policy. Windows doesn't have Unix domain sockets, and the most recent versions of the installer don't even use a `postgres` OS user, so it makes sense that it implements a different default security policy.

If a password is blank and the `pg_hba.conf` requires a password for the particular database/user/origin of an incoming connection, then the connection is rejected. There's no difference between a blank password and a lack of password.